# FindFit algorithm?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Does anyone know how to program a mathematica algorithm that does the same thing that `FindFit` does? Is there documentation of it somewhere?  I assume it is a least squares algorithm but with very generalized arguments. I ask because I'm trying to use 'weighted' least squares and it basically involves just one more factor.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit[]` can handle weighted nonlinear least squares.

Answer (score 4):

> `Fit` works using singular value decomposition. `FindFit` uses the same method for the linear least-squares case, the Levenberg–Marquardt method for nonlinear least-squares, and general `FindMinimum` methods for other norms.

[- source](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

`NonlinearModelFit` allows fitting of weighted data, as J.M. commented

**Edit:**

The best fit parameters are a property of the model:

```
p = Table[Prime[x], {x, 20}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[p, a x Log[b + c x], {a, b, c}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1.42076, b -> 1.65558, c -> 0.534645}
> ```

Comment: How do I get the list parameters from NonlinearModel? FindFit outputs such a thing

Comment: @minusatwelfth see my edit.

Comment: @minus, it's all in the docs, if you'd look for them.