# Algorithm used by Fit[]

Tags: fitting, implementation-details

Does anyone know what algorithm *Mathematica*'s basic `Fit[]` function uses? Is it proprietary?

I'm trying to do some pretty basic, linear, polynomial data fitting (albeit with poly degrees of about 15) in IDL but I'm finding that *Mathematica*'s `Fit[]` function does a better job, and fails less often, than any of IDL's routines. So I was hoping to find out which algorithm `Fit[]` is using and translate it into IDL.

And for the record, if I use `FindFit[..., Method->Automatic]` it gives the same results as `Fit[]`. In another [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98324/findfit-algorithm) it was stated that `FindFit[]` defaults to the SVD algorithm if no `Method` is specified, so I wonder if this is the algorithm used by `Fit[]` as well (or perhaps just a matrix inversion).

Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Yes, [it uses SVD under the hood](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#20880).

Comment: Almost certainly using SVD as @J.M. notes. For fitting degree 15 polynomials though you might want to consider a basis other than the standard one (1,x,x^2,...) to get better numeric stability.

Comment: J. M. and Daniel, thanks. Daniel, maybe Legendre Polynomials?

Interesting that IDL's svdfit() function and Mathematica's Fit[] function give very different results using SVD. I suppose the devil is in the details.

Comment: You could consider using Gram polynomials if your abscissas are equispaced; otherwise, the Chebyshev or Legendre basis can be used.

Comment: J. M., thanks for the advice. My abscissa are not equally spaced so I'll try Chebyshev and/or Legendre.